# Magento 2.2: Where is the block of template html?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, html

I need to add a conditional by checking the information of an custom attribute, for example if it is 'S' to show the address, if it is 'B' not to show the address

I need to modify the next template:

> \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\address-renderer\default.html

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
<!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
        <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value != null -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko --><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: element[attribute].value == null -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute] --><!-- /ko --><br/>
        <!-- /ko -->
     <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
<button type="button"
        class="action edit-address-link"
        data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
</button>
<!-- /ko -->
<button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
</button>
```

Where does Magento get the **address()** object?

Answer (score 1):

Hope Doing well.

please find this model file and you have address function here! which is used to get address.

> ```
> Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
> ```

this are the functions. please do some debugging by your self.

```
/**
 * Retrieve quote billing address
 *
 * @return Address
 */
public function getBillingAddress()
{
    return $this->_getAddressByType(Address::TYPE_BILLING);
}

/**
 * Retrieve quote shipping address
 *
 * @return Address
 */
public function getShippingAddress()
{
    return $this->_getAddressByType(Address::TYPE_SHIPPING);
}

protected function _getAddressByType($type)
{
    foreach ($this->getAddressesCollection() as $address) {
        if ($address->getAddressType() == $type && !$address->isDeleted()) {
            return $address;
        }
    }

    $address = $this->_quoteAddressFactory->create()->setAddressType($type);
    $this->addAddress($address);
    return $address;
}
```

**magento get shipping address data from here.**

> magento_directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/list.js

**line no. 35**

```
 quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(function (address) {
                self.createRendererComponent(address);
            });
```

please find this things and do some debugging by your self you will definitely get your result.

Thanks